# Equivalent of R quantile with parameter type=6

Tags: python, r, pandas, statistics, stata

I'm trying to port a Stata model to Python, and find some gap between Stata's `centile` and Python's `pandas.DataFrame.describe`:

- Stata:    1%: -.1657010273898333, 99%: .1683179750819993
- Python: 1%: -0.1647677302502512, 99: 0.1607038771234249

I cannot tell how they compute this per the official doc (http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?centile, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html). But when I tried the same data set in R:

```
> quantile(d[, c('V1')], c(0.01, 0.99), type=5)
    1%        99% 
-0.1650828  0.1652275 
> quantile(d[, c('V1')], c(0.01, 0.99), type=6)
   1%       99% 
-0.165701  0.168318
```

It appears that with parameter `type=6`, the result is identical to Stata. The API doc for quantile (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) indicates the following:

```
Type 6
     m = p. p[k] = k / (n + 1). Thus p[k] = E[F(x[k])]. This is used by Minitab and by SPSS.
```

I failed to find any existing Python library which has the same implementation.

Comment: The method used by Stata can be found in [[R] centile](http://stata.com/manuals13/rcentile.pdf), _Methods and formulas_ section.

Comment: the code to implement it is `stats:::quantile.default`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the same result as R's quantile, use `numpy.percentile`:

```
import numpy as np

np.percentile(range(1, 101), 100*(3/8))
# 38.125, same as R quantile(1:100, 3/8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Roberto Ferrer! I've written a Python function based on http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rcentile.pdf, which produces the same result as Stata does:

```
def centile(arr, percentiles=[50]):
  result = {}

  s = np.sort(arr)
  n = len(s)

  for percent in percentiles: 
    R = float(n + 1) * percent / 100
    r, f = int(R), R - int(R)

    result['{0}%'.format(percent)] = float(s[r - 1]) + f * (s[r] - s[r - 1])

  return result
```

Comment: This gives different results than R quantile :)